# What is the easiest way to migrate from Oracle 11g into SQL Server 2008 Express?

Tags: oracle11g, sql-server-2008-express

I was working with Oracle 11g and now I wish to migrate into Microsoft SQL Server 2008 for academic learning purposes. I have my DDL in a .txt file with all the syntax compatible with Oracle. Now I have to create the same tables and insertions in SQL Server. What are the possible options to convert or import my existing database created in Oracle to SQL Server ?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this link

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh313159.aspx

It describes step by step the procedure of migrating ORACLE database to Microsoft Sql Server database.

Comment: The question was quite clear that all he had was a text file with the DDL in it, and not an Oracle installation. I am in the same position, no Oracle install, but some DDL SQL.

Answer (score 0):

To Convert Oracle 11g to SQL Server 2012, Microsoft provides a tool called SQL Server Migration Assistant for Oracle (SSMA).

Below are very high level steps:

1. Download SSMA for Oracle from this [Link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43689). Make sure you have
   downloaded SSMA for Oracle and SSMA for Oracle Ext Pack. Install one
   after another.

   *Note: At the time of installation, it will give option for DB
   Instance and also for creation of Master password. Keep a note of
   them. You might need them later.*

   2. Open SSMA and create a new project.
   3. Connect to Oracle DB.
   4. Connect to SQL Server 2012.
   5. Convert schema of Oracle.
   6. Migrate data of Oracle.
   7. Synchronize with SQL Server.

[Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lKMR6KX5eCY) link for a straight forward conversion.
[MSDN PDF](http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/8/D/68D1B83D-284A-40C0-8D81-D2D1EA8A668C/Migration_from_Oracle_Database_to_SQL_Server_2012_FAQ.pdf) link for Datatype and other extensive information on the conversion.

*The above is only to get you started, even I am not sure about few options like Sequence and DBLinks. Good Luck.*

Comment: The question was quite clear that all he had was a text file with the DDL in it, and not an Oracle installation. I am in the same position, no Oracle install, but some DDL SQL.